# how to save canvas with two image

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

i have the canvas in which one image is displaying as it's background and other image is placed in the centre of that image. now i want to save that complete canvas. My recent code is not saving it..

you can see the demo here [ http://jsfiddle.net/himani/gqc9b0qd/3/ ]

```
var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
  ctx.lineWidth   = 6;
  ctx.lineJoin    = 'round';
  ctx.strokeRect(40,100,150,100);
     var angleInDegrees=0;
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Miscellaneous/Cartoon%20Characters/cartoon-characters-47a.jpg";
  ctx.drawImage(img,40,100,150,100);

 function drawRotated(degrees){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(40+150/2,100+100/2);
        ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.strokeRect(-150/2,-100/2,150,100);
        ctx.drawImage(img,-150/2,-100/2,150,100);
        ctx.restore();
    }
 $("#clockwise").click(function(){ 
        angleInDegrees+=30;
        drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
    });

$("#save").click(function(){ 

                var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

                if (ua.indexOf("Chrome") > 0) {
                    // save image without file type
          var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
                    document.location.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

                    // save image as png
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = "test1.png";
                    link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");;
                    link.click();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please use Chrome");
                }


    });
```

Comment: Your save fails because of a cross-origin restriction security error. All images you draw on the canvas must originate on the same domain as the webpage itself. You may draw images on the canvas from other domains, but if you do so you are no longer allowed to do `canvas.toDataURL()`.

Comment: @ markE then what can be done to make it correct..?

Comment: You must serve the images from the same domain as the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export with toDataUrl an image from a cross origin request, try define the **crossOrigin** attribute on your image.

```
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];    
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

    img.src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Miscellaneous/Cartoon%20Characters/cartoon-characters-47a.jpg";

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img,40,100,150,100);
    };
```

It worked just fine for me. Fore more information about this attributes and the availables values, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#Attributes

Comment: @ DePhileses img.crossOrigin line troubling me, image which is rotating is not loding coz of this and if click on rotate image button after second click it move down and stop rotating, and on clicking on save button only red colored border is getting save, but i want whole canvas to get save.. is it possible,what i want to get..??

Comment: @ DePhileses here i got this example but in this also that yellow colored circle is not getting stored with that image  [  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ramKpv ] but  i want both things to get save